# Default definition of white space method ws in a grammar

Tags: grammar, raku

According to [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#index-entry-ws) the default definition of the `ws` method in a grammar is to match zero or more whitespace characters, as long as that point is not within a word:

```
regex ws { <!ww> \s* }
```

What is the difference between this definition and the following:

```
regex ws { \s+ }
```

I wonder why the zero width assertion `<!ww>` is used instead of the simpler `\s+`? I also note that the default definition allows to match zero white spaces, but when would that actually happen? Wouldn't it be more clear if it used `\s+` instead of `\s*`?

Comment: Ok, so then the default `ws` will match between consecutive characters that are not word characters and not white space (like emojis). For example: `perl6 -e 'my $str="\c[carrot]\c[potato]"; say $str.split(/<!ww>\s*/).elems'` gives 4. Is this a reasonable behavior?

Comment: Larry considered it reasonable *default* behavior. The idea is that it works well for most typical grammars and if you want something else you just define your own `ws` rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ww` assertion means that there are chars matching `\w` either side of the current point. The `!` inverts it, meaning `<!ww>` matches:

- At the start of the string
- At the end of the string
- When there's a non-`\w` character before the current position (such as between "+" and "a")
- When there's a non-`\w` character after the current position (such as between "a" and "+")

Effectively, then, it means that whitespace can never be considered to occur between two word characters. However, between non-word characters, or between a word character and a non-word character, then there can be considered whitespace.

This follows what many languages we might wish to parse need. For example, consider `ab+cd`. The default `ws` will match either side of the `+`, but would not, for example, match within an identifier.

For languages where that isn't suitable, it's simply a matter of overriding the default `ws` for whatever that language needs.